# Facebook Login not working in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on an app which have facebook login,I have successfully impleameted it and tested several times,It was working perfectly,But from yesterday it stopped working without giving any error,I have debuged my app but couldnt found any issue,Can anyone please help me where is the issue is?

**Logcat**

```
04-26 13:03:54.397 5765-5765/com.abc.allaboutcity W/BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 5765
04-26 13:03:54.404 5765-5794/com.abc.allaboutcity E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f97c8e10b40
04-26 13:03:54.503 5765-5794/com.abc.allaboutcity E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f97c69aa370
04-26 13:03:54.749 5765-5794/com.abc.allaboutcity E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f97c69a9110
04-26 13:03:54.796 5765-6103/com.abc.allaboutcity W/chromium: [WARNING:spdy_session.cc(2527)] Received WINDOW_UPDATE for invalid stream 15
```

**java**

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize( getApplicationContext() );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_login );
        init();
        loginButton.registerCallback( callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.v( "Main", response.toString() );
                                setProfileToView( object );
                                new FACEBOOK_LOGIN().execute();
                            }
                        } );
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString( "fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday,cover,picture,first_name,last_name" );
                request.setParameters( parameters );
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                Toast.makeText( LoginActivity.this, "error to Login Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
        } );

  void init() {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
...
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Somebuddy is interested in just earning reputations by downvotes...better he can help....!!!

Comment: Whats your Logcat saying

Comment: wait ,I am sharing it by update my question,

Comment: It displays keystore missing message in your app ? when you try to login in the app

Comment: @KoVartthan - no,actually nothing happened after.Aftre successfully login,another screen that says "You are already authorised",when i clieck "OK".screen goes and nothing happens.

Comment: using `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0'` ??

Comment: using     compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check if you use the latest version for the Facebook SDK as they have changes in the Graph API and they deprecated some old versions.

Another thing which is not included in your code, is that in `LoginButton` you need to set the read permissions

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
```

Also be sure that you forward the login results with the `calbackManager` in `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

But could you clarify also where this code runs? is it in `Fragment` or an `Activity`.

Try to follow every step which is described here to be sure that you didn't miss something:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

Comment: Thanks for kind respones,but i have added read permission in my code.:( `   loginButton.setReadPermissions( Arrays.asList(
                "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends" ) );`

Comment: do you include also the `onActivityResult` part? if you add a breakpoint in the `onError` is it triggered? if it's not triggered then there is no error.

If there is not error in login then in the overriden method `onCompleted` of `GraphRequest.newMeRequest()` print `reponse.getError()` to see the result.